# Can't persist or find entities with JPA while tables are already in database

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I have a big problem with my DAO class, when I want to persist a new entity, I get a NullPointerException from my wildfly-server.

I have a ManagedBean called VeranstaltungAnlegenMB

```
package de.mb;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.facade.IVeranstaltungsverwaltungFacade;


@ManagedBean(name="veranstaltungAnlegenMB")
@RequestScoped
public class VeranstaltungAnlegenMB {

@EJB
IVeranstaltungsverwaltungFacade veranstaltungsverwaltungFacade;

private String name;
private String bezeichnung;

private String semester;
private int maxTeilnehmer;

public void veranstaltungAnlegen() {
    System.out.println("veranstaltungAnlegen() aufgerufen in VeranstaltungAnlegenMB");
    this.veranstaltungsverwaltungFacade.getVeranstaltungAnlegen().veranstaltungAnlegen(this.name, 
            this.bezeichnung, this.maxTeilnehmer, this.semester);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBezeichnung() {
    return bezeichnung;
}

public void setBezeichnung(String bezeichnung) {
    this.bezeichnung = bezeichnung;
}

public String getSemester() {
    return semester;
}

public void setSemester(String semester) {
    this.semester = semester;
}

public int getMaxTeilnehmer() {
    return maxTeilnehmer;
}

public void setMaxTeilnehmer(int maxTeilnehmer) {
    this.maxTeilnehmer = maxTeilnehmer;
}
}
```

The ManagedBean has a method veranstaltungAnlegen(), there I call my class VeranstaltungsverwaltungFacade (a stateless bean), it implements an local bean interface. The class VeranstaltungsverwaltungFacade hold my use cases. My use cases are all stateless beans and implements local bean interfaces too.

Here you see one of my use case class.

```
package de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.usecase.impl;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.dao.VeranstaltungDAO;
import de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.model.Veranstaltung;
import de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.usecase.ILehrveranstaltungAnlegen;

@Stateless
public class LehrveranstaltungAnlegenImpl implements  ILehrveranstaltungAnlegen {

@EJB
private VeranstaltungDAO veranstaltungDAO;

public LehrveranstaltungAnlegenImpl() {

}

@Override
public void veranstaltungAnlegen(String name, String bezeichnung, int maxTeilnehmer, String semester) {
    System.out.println(toString() + " starte Methode veranstaltungAnlegen(...)");
    Veranstaltung aVeranstaltung = new Veranstaltung(name, bezeichnung, maxTeilnehmer, semester);
    System.out.println("Veranstaltung: " + aVeranstaltung.getV_name() + " erstellt");
    veranstaltungDAO.save(aVeranstaltung);
    System.out.println(toString() + " veranstaltungAnlegen(String name, String bezeichnung, "
            + "int maxTeilnehmer, String semester)");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LehrveranstaltungAnlegenImpl";
}
}
```

My use case has my DAO class. When I try to save/persist my new entity I get a NullPointerException. I debugged my program and found out that my variable veranstaltungDAO has not been initialized --> null. But I don't know why, because I see in my console that the VeranstaltungDAO is deployed.

'[org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'VeranstaltungDAO' in deployment...'

Here you can see my DAO class:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import de.awk.dao.GenericDAO;
import de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.model.Veranstaltung;

@Stateless
public class VeranstaltungDAO extends GenericDAO<Veranstaltung>{

public VeranstaltungDAO() {
    super(Veranstaltung.class);
}
}
```

Here you see my entity class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;


import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Veranstaltung implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="V_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name="V_ID", sequenceName="SEQ_VERANSTALTUNG_ID", allocationSize=1)
private int v_id;
private String v_name;
private String v_bezeichnung;
private int max_Teilnehmer;
private String semester;

@ElementCollection
private List<String> studenten;

private String dozent;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="Veranstaltung_Hausarbeit",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="v_id", referencedColumnName="v_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="h_id", referencedColumnName="h_id"))
private List<Hausarbeit> hausarbeitenliste;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="Veranstaltung_Dokument",
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="v_id", referencedColumnName="v_id"),
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="d_id", referencedColumnName="d_id"))
private List<VeranstaltungDokument> dokumentenliste;

public Veranstaltung() {
}

public Veranstaltung(String v_name, String v_bezeichnung, int max_Teilnehmer, String semester) {
    this.v_name = v_name;
    this.v_bezeichnung = v_bezeichnung;
    this.max_Teilnehmer = max_Teilnehmer;
    this.semester = semester;
    this.dozent = "bla";
    this.hausarbeitenliste = new ArrayList<Hausarbeit>();
    this.dokumentenliste = new ArrayList<VeranstaltungDokument>();
    this.studenten = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public List<Hausarbeit> getHausarbeitenliste() {
    return hausarbeitenliste;
}

public void setHausarbeitenliste(List<Hausarbeit> hausarbeitenliste) {
    this.hausarbeitenliste = hausarbeitenliste;
}

public List<VeranstaltungDokument> getDokumentenliste() {
    return dokumentenliste;
}

public void setDokumentenliste(List<VeranstaltungDokument> dokumentenliste) {
    this.dokumentenliste = dokumentenliste;
}

public List<String> getStudenten() {
    return studenten;
}

public void setStudenten(List<String> studenten) {
    this.studenten = studenten;
}

public void addStudent(String student) {
    this.studenten.add(student);
}

public int getV_id() {
    return v_id;
}

public void setV_id(int v_id) {
    this.v_id = v_id;
}

public String getV_name() {
    return v_name;
}

public void setV_name(String v_name) {
    this.v_name = v_name;
}

public String getV_bezeichnung() {
    return v_bezeichnung;
}

public void setV_bezeichnung(String v_bezeichnung) {
    this.v_bezeichnung = v_bezeichnung;
}

public int getMax_Teilnehmer() {
    return max_Teilnehmer;
}

public void setMax_Teilnehmer(int max_Teilnehmer) {
    this.max_Teilnehmer = max_Teilnehmer;
}

public String getSemester() {
    return semester;
}

public void setSemester(String semester) {
    this.semester = semester;
}

public String getDozent() {
    return dozent;
}

public void setDozent(String dozent) {
    this.dozent = dozent;
}

public void addHausarbeit(Hausarbeit addHausarbeit) {
    this.hausarbeitenliste.add(addHausarbeit);
}
}
```

I hope you guys can help me.

---

My GenericsDAO which extends my class VeranstaltungDAO

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

public abstract class GenericDAO<T> {
private final static String UNIT_NAME = "EJB_JPA_LearningPortal";

@PersistenceContext(unitName = UNIT_NAME)
private EntityManager em;

private Class<T> entityClass;

public GenericDAO(){}

public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected void delete(Object id, Class<T> classe) {
    T entityToBeRemoved = em.getReference(classe, id);
    em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
}

public T update(T entity) {
    return em.merge(entity);
}

public void save(T entity) {
    this.em.persist(entity);
}

public T find(int entityID) {
    return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
}

// Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
// em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery()<T> method
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<T> findAll() {
    CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

// Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
// ery.getSingleResult()<T> method
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected T findOneResult(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    T result = null;
    try {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
        // Method that will populate parameters if they are passed not null and empty
        if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
            populateQueryParameters(query, parameters);
        }

        result = (T) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while running query: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

private void populateQueryParameters(Query query, Map<String, Object> parameters) {

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
        query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

public T findByString(String entityID) {
    return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
}

}
```

---

Here you can see my stack trace, I don't know how to format it better...

15:15:59,433 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-11) java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.usecase.impl.LehrveranstaltungAnlegenImpl.veranstaltungAnlegen(LehrveranstaltungAnlegenImpl.java:26)
    at de.mb.VeranstaltungAnlegenMB.veranstaltungAnlegen(VeranstaltungAnlegenMB.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    ... 44 more

15:15:59,442 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-11) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.awk.veranstaltungsverwaltung.usecase.impl.LehrveranstaltungAnlegenImpl.veranstaltungAnlegen(LehrveranstaltungAnlegenImpl.java:26)
    at de.mb.VeranstaltungAnlegenMB.veranstaltungAnlegen(VeranstaltungAnlegenMB.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: You did not show the method `dao.save`. Sure the DAO itself is null? Please show the stacktrace...

Comment: I have added, what you have asked for. I am very sure that the DAO is null, cause I debugged and saw that the variable is at that point null...